# Django Authentication and Login Issue with Class Based Views

Tags: django, django-forms, django-authentication

I am trying to achieve two different views: one for registration purpose and one for login purpose. 
Now, the registration process works perfectly but the authentication process does not.

Here's the code:

in forms.py the first form called UserForm is used to sign up users, the second form called LoginForm is used to log in users.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django import forms

class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'username', 'email', 'password']

class LoginForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password']
```

in views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, redirect
from .models import Step, Cycle, Program, MotorSetting, GeneralSetting
from django.views import generic
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView, UpdateView, DeleteView
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from django.views.generic import View
from .forms import UserForm
from .forms import LoginForm


class UserFormView(View):
form_class = UserForm
template_name = 'programs/registration_form.html'

# display blank form
def get(self, request):
    form = self.form_class(None)
    return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

#process form data
def post(self, request):
    form = self.form_class(request.POST)

    if form.is_valid():

        #storing the data but NOT SAVING them to db yet
        user = form.save(commit=False)

        #cleaning and normalizing data
        username = form.cleaned_data['username']
        password = form.cleaned_data['password']
        user.set_password(password)
        #saving to db
        user.save()

        #if credentials are correct, this returns a user object
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

        if user is not None:

            if user.is_active:

                login(request, user)
                return redirect('programs:index')

    return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})


class LoginFormView(View):
    form_class = LoginForm
    template_name = 'programs/login_form.html'

    # display blank form
    def get(self, request):
        form = self.form_class(None)
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

    #process form data
    def post(self, request):
        form = self.form_class(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():

            #storing the data but NOT SAVING them to db yet
            user = form.save(commit=False)

            #if credentials are correct, this returns a user object
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

            if user is not None:

                if user.is_active:

                    login(request, user)
                    return redirect('programs:index')

        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})
```

in app/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from . import views

app_name = 'programs'

urlpatterns = [

    #register page
    url(r'^register/$', views.UserFormView.as_view(), name='register'),

    #login page
    url(r'^login/$', views.LoginFormView.as_view(), name='login'),

]
```

The registration process goes smoothly, the authentication/login does not. When I fill in the form to login and press send, nothing happens apart from the form getting blank again.

Is there any error I'm not seeing in the code?

Many thanks!

Comment: A `ModelForm` is for creating or updating objects. You shouldn't use it to log in. Django comes with [views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/default/#module-django.contrib.auth.views) and [forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/default/#module-django.contrib.auth.forms) for logging users in. You should think about using these instead of writing your own, or at least look at how they work.

Comment: you're obviously not passing the test `if form.is_valid()` (otherwise your code would crash at the line `user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)` since `username` and `password` are undefined. And the reason is that as said above, your ModelForm is trying to validate a new user with the credentials you give. A user with an already existing username is not valid...

Comment: Also for registration: You should not create a user using form.save(), the Django User management model has a `create_user` method that ensure the user is created properly. Use the built-in views for what you're trying to do, it'll cover all the security as well: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/default/#module-django.contrib.auth.views

Comment: @dirkgroten thank you for the suggestion. I had a look at the documentation, but I don't find it particularly easy for beginners. For example: after I've added from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views to urls.py and the proper url path for login, how do I define the class LoginView in views.py? Should I add and edit all the attributes such as template_name, redirect_field_name, etc? Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: No, normally you shouldn't have to change LoginView, it's already defined for you. You have to create the login template though and if it's not located at the default location `registration/login.html` then you want to pass to `LoginView` the attribute `template_name` when initialising it in your URL patterns. For example you can just set `template_name` to your own template. The documentation has an example `login.html` template that you can use as a starting point.

Comment: To summarise: For registration of new users, you still need to create form, view and template. But for all other authentication related stuff (login, logout, password management) you only need to define the URL pattern to use the existing Django Views (which also provide a form) and create the .html templates to display the forms.

Comment: @dirkgroten Okay thanks, the concept is clear now. I deleted my previous login form from forms.py and I added the following code to my urls.py: from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views          #login page
    url(r'^accounts/login/$', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(), name='login'),      however, I'm getting the error: AttributeError: module 'django.contrib.auth.views' has no attribute 'LoginView'.  What is going on now? Again, thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Which version of Django are you using? `LoginView` was only added in Django 1.11. Before that, it had a function based view `login`.

Comment: @Alasdair I'm using 1.10.7. Should I upgrade?

Comment: That's up to you. The advantages of upgrading are that 1.11.x is the latest version, is an LTS release, and contains `LoginView`. However, you don't have to upgrade. Django 1.10.x is still supported, so you can stick with 1.10 and use `django.contrib.auth.views.login` instead of `django.contrib.auth.views.LoginView`.

Comment: Thank you very much Alasdair and dirkgroten for getting me out of troubles! I have upgraded to the new version and now the LoginView works as expected. Thank you!!!